# Hibernate: @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) does not work on non-primary key referenced column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, one-to-one

I have 2 tables: `Order [OrderId(PK), OrderShipmentCode, ...]` and `Shipment[ShipmentId(PK), ShipmentCode, ...]`.

In `Order` class, I declared `shipment` field as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "OrderShipmentCode", referencedColumnName = "ShipmentCode", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Shipment shipment;
```

When I get the list of `Order`, the `Shipment` is also loaded (I saw many separate SELECT queries). But I want the `Shipment` to be lazy loaded, not to be fetched together with `Order`.

For other tables, if the referenced column is primary key then the results are as expected (Lazy-loading is used). In my case, `ShipmentCode` is not Primary Key of `Shipment` table, and lazy-loading is not used by Hibernate.

Could you show me how to accomplish that goal?

**EDIT:**
The Query code is as bellow:

```
Criteria criteria = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Order.class);
List result = criteria.list();
```

SQL queries are: 1 SELECT statement for `Order` table and a bunch of SELECT statement for `Shipment`

Comment: Can you show the code for criteria or query being fired?

Comment: you can try using a native query like select * from order where condition.

Comment: If you know that the joined object is never null you can use `optional=false`. Hibernate then can lazily load the relation. See this super helpful post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331907/what-is-the-difference-between-manytooneoptional-false-vs-columnnullable-f

Answer (score 2):

Thd problem is caused by the [HHH-13024 issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13024).

In the true spirit of OSS, you might want to investigate the problem and send a Pull Request with a fix proposal. That's the fastest way of getting an issue fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I already tried your solution but the result is the same

Comment: I also tested with your updated answer but the results are still the same.

Comment: I agree with that. Check this post for more detail (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987638/hibernate-one-to-one-lazy-loading-optional-false)

Answer (score 1):

If you worry about multiple select queries while loading, you can overcome this by using Entity Graphs. please refer to below link for more details
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Criteria criteria = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
                                 .getCurrentSession()
                                 .createCriteria(Order.class)
                                 .setFetchMode("shipment", FetchMode.LAZY);
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your solution

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@JsonIgnore` over the shipment field of order. If you are giving using `MappedBy` over shipment field then removing it might solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

add to your entity field with shipmentCode and set your code for relation, then it`s fork fine

```
@Column(name = "shipmentCode")
private Long shipmentCode;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "OrderShipmentCode", referencedColumnName = "shipmentCode", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Shipment shipment;
```

If you use Lazy-init you entity extracting without fild with relation value, then when you trying extract lazy entity Hibernate can`t find any values becouse it havent relation value