# JPA: Which should I use? Basic(optional) or Column(nullable)?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

For simple string field,

```
@Entity
class Foo {

    //1. @Basic(optional = false)
    //2. @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    String name;
}
```

I need to restrict name's length using `@Column` annotation, but I'm confused with the nullable attribute. While I'm using other annotations like `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` those use `optional` attributes, I feel like to use `@Basic(optional)` to keep most annotations uniform. But I can't restrict the name's length with `@Basic`.

So, where should I annotate the nullable attribute, by `@Basic` or `@Column`?

*EDIT*

Simply say, in which form would you prefer:

Form 1:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(length = 100)
    String name;
}
```

Form 2:

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    String name;
}
```

Well personally I like Form 1, because `optional` attribute is also used by `@ManyToOne` etc. annotations, but Form 2 is also good because it's done in single annotation.

**EDIT**

After read http://markmail.org/message/osod6rsauwbnkvya, I've got the difference between `@Basic.optional` and `@Column.nullable`. But I still don't know which one I should use. It seems like good to include both annotations, so make the underlying table well defined, and check null in JPA before the actual update maybe slightly faster.

Comment: possible duplicate of [@Basic(optional = false) vs @Column(nullable = false) in JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899073/basicoptional-false-vs-columnnullable-false-in-jpa)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From API documentation:

[**@Basic:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html)

> @Basic annotation is the simplest type
>   of mapping to a database column. The
>   Basic annotation can be applied to a
>   persistent property or instance
>   variable of any of the following
>   types: Java primitive types, wrappers
>   of the primitive types, String,
>   java.math.BigInteger,
>   java.math.BigDecimal, java.util.Date,
>   java.util.Calendar, java.sql.Date,
>   java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp,
>   byte[], Byte[], char[], Character[],
>   enums, and any other type that
>   implements Serializable.

[**@Column**](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html)

> @Column Is used to specify a mapped
>   column for a persistent property or
>   field. If no Column annotation is
>   specified, the default values are
>   applied.

So, if you don't specify `@Column` it derives column value from getter/setter.
If you need to specify column name you have to `@Column` annotation.

`@Basic` allows you to specify Fetch Type. If you want to change default fetching type you have to use this annotation, otherwise you can omit it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899073/basicoptional-false-vs-columnnullable-false-in-jpa

Comment: @Reddy - So, only `@Basic` is like saying that make the database column `NOT NULL` for said variable ? Then why have two ways of doing the same thing ?