# @Basic(optional = false) vs @Column(nullable = false) vs @NotNull

Tags: hibernate, validation, jpa, jsr

Of the three options, should I be using one or two or all three combined to prevent null values?

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "SOME_VALUE", nullable = false)
@Basic(optional = false)
private String someValue;
```

**Note that I don't consider this a duplicate of an existing question.** I see [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899073/basicoptional-false-vs-columnnullable-false-in-jpa) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439504/confusion-notnull-vs-columnnullable-false) that ask about a subset of these three options but have yet to find one that asks about which of the three is appropriate to use in a modern JPA/Hibernate stack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion: @NotNull vs @Column(nullable = false)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439504/confusion-notnull-vs-columnnullable-false)

Comment: @Zeus, I already explained why I think this is NOT a dupe of that exact question.

Comment: If you are using a validator, then `@NotNull` will generate an exception before a query is made. If you are using `@Column(nullable = false)` and you are generating the tables using JPA, you will get an exception upon insert/update. `@Basic(optional = false)` is also used during schema generation, so the exception will be generated upon insert/update due to constraint violation, same as with `@Column(nullable = false)`. In general automated validation results in less-meaningful error messages than desired, so you might want to do it manually.

Answer (score 5):

**@NotNull**

1. Belongs to `javax.validation.constraints` package.
2. As part of schema creation, not null constraint is created on DB column.
3. Is handled by validation engine(VE).
4. If a property is not set(or set to null), while persisting, VE throws an exception.
5. As property validation is
   handled by a VE, useful in non-persistence layers such as UI
   layer(JSF).

**@Basic(optional=false)**

1. Belongs to `javax.persistence` package.
2. As part of schema creation, not null constraint is created on DB column.
3. Is handled by persistence provider(PP).
4. If a property is not set(or set to null) while persisting, the PP does not pass statement to DB; it throws an exception.

**@Column(nullable=false)**

1. Belongs to `javax.persistence` package.
2. As part of schema creation, not null constraint is created on DB column.
3. Is handled by persistence provider(PP).
4. If a property is not set(or set to null) while persisting, the PP does not pass statement to DB; it throws an exception.
5. Allows to specify addtional parameters like column name(which can be different from property name).

Comment: What about `@ManyToOne(optional = false)`. Does it follow the same rules as those listed for `@Basic(optional=false)`?