# Object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

When I try to save the data this error is shown:

> com.LTR.entity.Silicon.platform -> com.LTR.entity.Platform,

It says that I need to save the transient.

I have been trying to put cascadeType.ALL but this does not work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="silicon",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"silicon_visual_id"})})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@DynamicUpdate
public class Silicon implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="mir", unique = false, nullable = true)
    private Long mir;

    @Column(name = "silicon_name", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private String siliconName;

    @Column(name = "type_silicon", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private String typeSilicon;

    @Column(name = "qdf", nullable = true, length= 45)
    private String qdf;

    @Column(name = "silicon_visual_id", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private String siliconVisualId;

    @Column(name = "cpu_id", nullable = true, length= 45)
    private String cpuId;

    @Column(name = "stepping", nullable = true, length= 45)
    private String stepping;

    @Column(name = "socket", nullable = true, length= 45)
    private String socket;

    @Column(name = "status_silicon", nullable = false,length= 45)
    private String statusSilicon;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_owner", nullable = false)
    private User userOwner;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "date_admission", nullable = false)
    private Date dateAdmission;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_request", nullable = true)
    private User userRequest;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_last_returned", nullable = true)
    private User userLastReturned;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "date_delivered", nullable = true)
    private Date dateDelivered;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="platform_current", nullable = true)
    private Platform platform;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="platform_own", nullable = true,updatable= false)
    private Platform platformOwn;

    /*GETTERS AND SETTERS*/
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="platform")
public class Platform implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="platform_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long platformId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="locationId", nullable = false)
    private Location location;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @JoinColumn(name="businessUnit", nullable = true)
    private BusinessUnit businessUnit;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length= 45,unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "project", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private String project;

    @Column(name = "serialPlatform", nullable = false, length= 45, unique 
        = true)
    private String serialPlatform;

    @Column(name = "model", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "chasisSerial", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private String chasisSerial;

    @Column(name = "chasisModel", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private String chasisModel;

    @Column(name = "ismpKitName", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private String ismpKitName;

    @Column(name = "ismpSerialNumber", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private String ismpSerialNumber;

    @Column(name = "assignedTo", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private String assignedTo;

    @Column(name = "OwnedBy", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private String OwnedBy;

    @Column(name = "ismNumber", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private int ismNumber;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "receivedDate", nullable = false)
    private Date receivedDate;

    @Column(name = "asset", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private int asset;

    @Column(name = "startStatus", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private boolean startStatus;

    @Column(name = "finalStatus", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private boolean finalStatus;

    @Column(name = "cloudReady", nullable = false, length= 45)
    private boolean cloudReady;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="platform")
    private List<Annotation> annotations;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy 
        = "platform")
    private Set<Silicon> userRole = new HashSet<Silicon>();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "platform")
    private Host Host;

    /*GETTERS AND SETTERS*/
```

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.LTR.entity.Silicon.platform -> com.LTR.entity.Platform; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.LTR.entity.Silicon.platform -> com.LTR.entity.Platform
```

```
2019-09-09 08:32:43.161 ERROR 21968 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.LTR.entity.Silicon.platform -> com.LTR.entity.Platform]
2019-09-09 08:32:43.172  INFO 21968 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] com.LTR.controller.SiliconController     : org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.LTR.entity.Silicon.platform -> com.LTR.entity.Platform; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.LTR.entity.Silicon.platform -> com.LTR.entity.Platform
```

```
2019-09-09 09:25:45.500  WARN 8000 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2019-09-09 09:25:45.500 ERROR 8000 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'owned_by' cannot be null
2019-09-09 09:25:45.506 ERROR 8000 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
2019-09-09 09:25:45.517  INFO 8000 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] com.LTR.controller.SiliconController     : org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

I dont know why when i tried to update or insert this crashed with this error
, and also this only happens when the platform object is null when i try to update

when i set cascadeType.ALL it sasys that the ownedBy from the platform entity is empty but in the database is no empty

Comment: Can you paste the code, that causes the exception?

Comment: There is the exception code

Comment: @JustinZuñigaTorres Do you want to ignore platform when saving Silicon? right? so you don't want to persist, right?

Answer (score 4):

You need to save Platform before saving Silicon so Persist is the CascadeType you would need here.

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="platform_current", nullable = true)
private Platform platform;
```

Comment: yes now it shows me that the ownedBy from the platform emptity is null, but in the database is not null

Answer (score 0):

Add cascade="all" attribute to all attributes.

Like below

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, optional=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="platform_current", nullable = true)
private Platform platform;
```

You need to set `optional=true`.

The @Column(nullable=true) is to instruct the DDL generation tool to include a NULL SQL column type constraint.

For more on optional vs nullable, check out [this StackOverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899073/basicoptional-false-vs-columnnullable-false-in-jpa)

Comment: 2019-09-09 09:20:15.628  WARN 2004 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2019-09-09 09:20:15.632 ERROR 2004 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'owned_by' cannot be null

Comment: i put cascadeType.ALL and now it shows this error yes the column can nat be null but in the database is not null

Comment: optional=true is the default so no need to add it. `CascadeType.ALL` did the trick for me.